# Python-Sphinx: docstring code-testing along with running code by IPython directive?

Tags: python, ipython, python-sphinx, doctest

Sphinx supports a `doctest` directive, for including tests of code within docstrings. The code is displayed with the `>>>` prompt of the standard Python interpreter.

Sphinx also supports an `ipython` directive, for rendering Jupyter/IPython cells that run code passed to the directive, and the directive and its code arguments can also be included in docstrings.

Question: is it possible to test the code passed to the `ipython` directive in a docstring, while at the same time running and displaying it in Jupyter/IPython cells, rather than using the `>>>` prompt?